# Schedule time UX

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, layout, user-centered-design, users

[image: Current Status]

What I am trying to solve from the above screen shot is scheduling update. With the new update "to" field is optional, and not required field and also the UI and wording is confusing as when Run Start time is mentioned, it can run untill it is finished and End time is just optional in case you dont want to run system entirely to finish its job. With the new update, End time is an optional field and what I am thinking are the following two. Please let me know your feedback or better idea

Thinking something like; 
Start time: **:** 
End time: **:** OPTIONAL!

Start time: **:** O Run until completed (default) 
O Run until **:** 
where O is radio buttons
it can be "to" instead of "end"

FYI: Where it says Run, you can imagine example of antivirus. Where you want to scan your laptop at particular time untill it is done or you want to provide some end time ( no matter it will finish entire scan) but will stop at that time. It is very similar in this case, As of now end time is required but with new update, end time will be optional. thanks everyone for help.

Comment: It seems to me that what you're after isn't really a from/to so much as 'start at ___' + *optionally* 'time out after ___ hrs/mins'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Is this what you're looking for? In this one I grayed out the `end time` box because `Run until completion` is selected by default. To make it easier for the user, I also put a default value into the text boxes. For example, for the start time you can put the time an hour from now, or the time that the users computer is least likely to be used (or anything else that may work better for your app). And likewise, for the second text box you can put a time that's a couple hours after the first time.